# How to pass Credentials to WCF service for Windows Authentication from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf, wcf-security, wcf-data-services, wcf-client

I have enabled my WCF service for Windows Authentication. How can I pass Credentials to Service from From Silverlight application.
For Credentials I can get User name and domain by code *WebContext.Current.User.DisplayName*. But how I will get client password through code.
*serviceClient.Credentials = newSystem.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "Password", "Domian");*

Answer (score 1):

It should be done automatically if you have configured the client to use Windows authentication mode, please read following link:

[Use Windows Authentication to Secure a Service for Silverlight Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744835%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)